# it is giving me a error with position of with

Tags: mysql

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                     email, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, email 
                                        ORDER BY id, email) row_num     
              FROM requests_data)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1
```

Comment: MySQL allows CTE in SELECT only, not in DML.

Comment: Note that it can be quicker to construct a new table, retaining only those rows you wish to keep. Then drop the old table. Then rename (and if necessary, re-index) the new table.

Comment: they are giving me an error with (with statement)

Comment: strawberry, am not getting your point

Comment: @Akina - CTEs are permitted in DELETE statements. You just cant delete from a CTE as you cannot also delete from a subquery.

Comment: @NarinderSingla: (1) please share the entire error messag (2) Please tell us wich version of MySQL you are running (`select version()` will tell you) (3) What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel CTE in fact is a part of non-changed SELECT subquery. Yes, WITH clause can be placed not only immediately before the corresponding SELECT, but also at the very beginning of the DML query - but it will still only be used in the SELECT subquery which' result will not be changed (acts as read-only table).

Comment: PS. But in general, the term "minimal email" is very strange... Even `ANY_VALUE(email)` makes more sense.

Comment: @GMB unrecognized statement type.(near with) and version of mysql is 10.4.11

Comment: @GMB Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)
SQL query: Copy Documentation

WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email ) row_num FROM sales.contacts ) DELETE FROM cte WHERE row_num > 1

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1' at line 16

Comment: @Akina - Where is the "SELECT subquery" here: `with cte as (...) delete t from cte join t using(id) where cte.rn > 1` - Which could work just fine, if there ony were a primary key present.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `cte` in FROM is a subquery - it is not a table. Your query is `delete t from (...) as cte join t using(id) where cte.rn > 1` rewritten using CTE, not more.

Comment: @Akina - I guess, I get what you mean now (after rereading the comments). The magic word is **readonly**. With that I agree. But I don't agree with "MySQL allows CTE in SELECT only". It's confusing. The CTE in my example is not **in** any "SELECT". For MariaDB your first comment might even be correct.

Answer (score 0):

By way of illustration of my comment, consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'adam@pmail.con'),
(1,'ben@pmail.con'),
(1,'charlie@pmail.con'),
(1,'dave@pmail.con'),
(2,'alice@pmail.con'),
(2,'bertha@pmail.con'),
(2,'carol@pmail.con'),
(2,'diana@pmail.con'),
(2,'erica@pmail.con');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_new_table;

CREATE TABLE my_new_table AS
SELECT id,MIN(email) email FROM my_table GROUP BY id;

DROP TABLE my_table;

RENAME TABLE my_new_table TO my_table;

SELECT * FROM my_table;

+----+-----------------+
| id | email           |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | adam@pmail.con  |
|  2 | alice@pmail.con |
+----+-----------------+
```